# Server IP is showing Firewall IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, firewall, ip

From server 2008 r2, I check "what is my IP address", instead of showing my server IP, it showed my Firewall IP. How to rectify this.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you cannot : the typical situation is that your server is on a private subnet behind the firewall, and any outbound traffic to the Internet (such as a "What's My IP" site) is NATed on the firewall to the latter's public IP Address. The website has no way of knowing what your server's original IP was.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, it would show your external IP address (this is assuming you are going to www.whatismyipaddress.com)

If you want your internal Ip -

- Open command prompt
- Type `ipconfig`

That is unless you are thinking you you have a one-to-one nat setup and its not working? more info is required.